# IntegrityError at. insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have been doing my head in with this one. I am importing data in django using CSV, but that isn't my problem.

Get this error when inserting data:

```
IntegrityError at /import-user-profile/
insert or update on table "association_userprofile_club" violates foreign key constraint "association_userprofile_club_club_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (club_id)=(0) is not present in table "association_club".
```

Using postgreSQL, not sure if thats the reason.

Here is the relevant models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    membership_number = models.CharField(max_length=30,help_text='Membership number.')
    club = models.ManyToManyField(Club)
    date_joined = models.DateField(blank=True)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text='Max 100 characters.',blank=True)
    suburb = models.CharField(max_length=40,help_text='Max 40 characters.',blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10,help_text='Max 6 characters.',blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30,help_text='Max 4 characters.',blank=True)
    home_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30,help_text='Max 30 characters.',blank=True)
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30,help_text='Max 30 characters.',blank=True)
    ticketed_steward = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('0', 'No'), ('1', 'Yes')],blank=True)
    ticketed_time_keeper = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('0', 'No'), ('1', 'Yes')],blank=True)
    AFA_judge = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('0', 'No'), ('1', 'Yes')],blank=True)
    associate_members = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True, related_name='+')

    def __str__(self):  
          return "%s's profile" % self.membership_number
```

and

```
class Club(models.Model):
    club_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text='Name of the club, MAX 50 characters.')
    club_coordinater = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    contact_fax = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    address_location = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    address_suburb = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    address_postcode = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    address_state = models.CharField(max_length=4,help_text='State the club is in, MAX 4 characters.',blank=True)
    incorporated = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=[('0', 'No'), ('1', 'Yes')],blank=True)
    old_id = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    joined = models.DateField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.club_name
```

This should be working as club is being properly returned in.

```
def import_user_profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        file = database_loc + "tblHandlers.csv"
        data = ""
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if row[0] != "pkMemberNumber":
                    #0:pkMemberNumber 1:Club 2:fldContactOpen 3:fldLastName 4:fldFirstName 5:fldStreet 6:fldSuburb 7:fldState 8:fldPostcode 9:fldHome 10:fldMobile 11:fldEmail 12:fldJunior 13:fldNewsletter 14:fldNotes 15:dtejoined 16:dteExpiry 17:dateRenewed 18:fldFinMem1 19:fldFinMem2 20:fldDOB 21:fldHanderAge 22:fldStewTicket 23:fldTimeTicket 24:fldSnrTimeTicket
                    user = User.objects.get(username=row[0]+row[4]+row[3])

                    try:
                        club = Club.objects.get(club_name=str(row[1]))
                        club.save()
                    except:
                        club = Club.objects.get(club_name="No Club")
                        club.save()

                    try:
                        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
                    except:
                        profile = UserProfile(user=user)

                    #profile.user=user
                    profile.membership_number=row[0]
                    thing = str(club.id)
                    profile.club=thing
                    profile.date_joined=date_re(row[15])
                    profile.street_address=row[5]
                    profile.suburb=row[6]
                    profile.postcode=row[8]
                    profile.state=row[7]
                    profile.home_phone=row[9][0:30]
                    profile.mobile_phone=row[10]
                    profile.ticketed_steward=row[22]
                    profile.ticketed_time_keeper=row[23]
                    profile.AFA_judge="0"
                    profile.save()

                    user_receipts = UserReceipts(user_id=profile.id,recept="",date_paid=date_re(row[17]),membership_valid_to=date_re(row[16]))  
        html = "<html><body>" + data + "</body></html>"
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

Django says the issue occurs at this:

```
profile.club=thing
```

Some help with this would save my sanity! Thanks

Comment: I think auto-declared ids are numbers. So you're assigning an string to a number because you're calling `str()`.

Comment: if i remove str() from club.id the result is TypeError at /import-user-profile/
add() argument after * must be a sequence, not int

Comment: OH! that's because it is a ManyToMany relation. You Can't assing a single instance to it. Ill add the solution to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 try:
     club = Club.objects.get(club_name=str(row[1]))
     club.save() # <-- You don't need to save. You haven't changed anything on the club.
 except:
     club = Club.objects.get(club_name="No Club")
     club.save() # <-- You don't need to save. You haven't changed anything on the club.
```

And model ids declared by django are numeric, so don't use `thing = str(club.id)`.

Also, using the attribute `pk` is preferable over `id` because `pk` will always point to the real primary key name. This means if you ever change the primary key of your models, you won't need to change all the `id` accesses in your code.

You need to change `profile.club=thing` to `profile.club.add(club.pk)` because your `club` attribute is declared as a `models.ManyToManyField(Club)` which is a sequence of `Club` objects, not a single one.

Or... you may change it and use a `models.ForeignKey(Club)` which is more coherent with the attribute name (`club`) (do this only in case that your users can only be members of one club at the same time)

Comment: Thanks so much Adrián you saved my sanity! I had been tinkering with it for too long.

It makes sense now because i accessed this table 'association_userprofile_club'.

Answer (score 0):

When this error happens, what is tends to be related to is that you made a mistake when creating one or more foreign key fields for your model.

First of all ***make sure*** your model foreign key fields are pointing to the right table.

For instance, if you have the following model:

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    ...
    model_b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, ...)
    model_c = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, ...) # <-- wrong model in foreign key
    ...
```

You might be accidentally using ModelB on both foreign keys, where you should instead be using ModelC:

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    ...
    model_b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, ...)
    model_c = models.ForeignKey(ModelC, ...) # <-- correct model in foreign key
    ...
```

Otherwise, when you try to create a new model instance of model A:

```
>>> ModelA.objects.create(model_b_id=<int>, model_c_id=<int>)
```

Since `model_c_id` is setting a value for an id for `ModelB`, this may throw an error because you are looking for a foreign key that exists in `ModelC` table, and that does not necessarely exists for the `ModelB` table.